# determining the number of variables in the kernel of a U-stat

Tags: self-study, estimation, decision-theory

I'm working through some problems on deriving U-statistics, and I am unsure about determining the number of samples (random variables?) that are needed for the kernel of a given U-stat. For example:

Let $X_i$ be $iid$ with unknown Lesbegue PDF. Let $\mu = EX_1$, $\sigma^2 = VAR(X_1)$ and $EX^4 < \infty$. For $\theta = \mu\sigma^2$, find a U-stat for $\theta$.

Consider,

$$g(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \frac{x_1(x_2-x_3)^2 + x_2(x_1-x_3)^2 + x_3(x_1-x_2)^2}{6}$$

as a potential kernel that is unbiased for $\theta$ and symmetric in its arguments. However, my initial thought was to use:

$$h(x_1,x_2) = \frac{x_1(x_1-x_2)^2 + x_2(x_1-x_2)^2}{4}$$

which is also unbiased for $\theta$ and symmetric in its arguments. Either I am making a mistake in calculating the $Eh(x_1,x_2)$ or I am missing something about the 'estimability' of $\mu\sigma^2$ with only 2 samples.

Thanks!

Comment: The expectation of your kernel involves third moments and thus cannot be unbiased for a parameter based on the first two moments.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Someone in my class had also pointed out to me that X is not necessarily independent of itself (usually it is not) something I had forgotten. But this clarifies the more general question I had on U-stat's and the Kernal